# Please help, mounting other partitions on startup

Tags: 13.04, automount, partitioning

### These are my all partitions.

[image]

### This is my /etc/fstab

[image]

I would like to auto mount sda3 (NTFS), sda6 (ext4), sda7 (ext4) on startup, please help me edit the /etc/fstab file.

I've searched for GUI way of doing this but I cannot find **pysdm** on the software center.

Thanks.

### Edited!!!

[image]

I've edited fstab as shown in the picture, I got error during booting, please help me find out what went wrong.
P.S. I've created /mnt/extdisk1, I copied and pasted the UUID so it was not misspelling.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, type the following in a terminal:

```
sudo blkid
```

This should give you the UUIDs of all your partitions.

Once you have the UUIDs you need, editing your fstab is not actually that hard. You need to enter information into 6 columns, each separated by some white space.

- For the first column, add the UUID of the partition you want to mount (which you obtained from the blkid command).
- In the second column, enter where you would like to mount the partition. I usually place all my extra hard disks in /mnt/extdisk1 /mnt/extdisk2 etc.... *Note that you will need to create the above directories using `sudo mkdir /mnt/extdisk1` etc...*
- For the third column, enter the type of file system the partition uses (ntfs, ext3, etc...)
- For the fourth column, enter the options you would like to use. I would just specify `defaults`. If you have an ssd, its good to also put `noatime nodiratime discard`. Discard enables TRIM support for your SSD - ensuring longer life.
- For the fifth column just enter 0
- For the last column, enter the pass value you would like to give it. This is a number specifying in which order you would like to mount the partition (just make it sequential and you'll be fine).

If you want more information you can take a look at the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fstab) for fstab.

Comment: Do I have to fix **errors=remount-ro** on my /dev/sda5/, or just leave it like that?

Comment: You can put it as an option if you want. That option will basically attempt to remount your drive in the case an error occurs which causes it to dismount.

Comment: Please look at my edit.

Comment: What error did it give you? Are you sure ext4 is the file system for that particular device? Also, just in case. Could you change `/mnt/extdisk1/` to `/mnt/extdisk1` (no last slash)